# How do I generate smart filtes using java?

Tags: java

I searched for word 'Book'. I am getting thousands of data containing 'Children Book', 'Adult's Book', 'Cook Book'. I want filters to generated which satisfy following criteria.

```
   Segment Name | Max products | Min Products | Priority
   Children Book| 74%          | 10%          | 1
   Adult's Book | 74%          | 10%          | 2
   Cook Book    | 74%          | 10%          | 3
```

if search result contains 74% of products of particular segment not to show that segment. Minimum products should be 10% of search result.
Based on Above conditions I want to generate a list which contains Author IDs

I also have data of previous week which contains for particular Segment which authors were searched most.

```
 Children Book->>{
     {123, 6}, 
     {456, 10},
     {789, 9}
},
Adult's Book->>{
    {769, 10}, 
    {345, 9}, 
    {987, 16}, 
    {234, 8}}
```

I have this in Hash Map where 123, 456 etc is Author ID and 6, 10 etc are count(No. of times Author is searched in previous week)
I am using Java. How to achieve this?

Comment: Show how you tried to solve the problem and where you failed, then you might get some help. This isn't place where you get someone to write your complete homework for free. Also there is no particular data structure in Java or elsewhere that would automagically solve your issue. What you want is to come up w/ algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: @Jan I have object called RefineResponse which contains list of Adult'sBook, Children Book but I am not able to figure out how to check which segment name should be applied to which response. Are you getting my point?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to achieve here. As mentioned by @Jan, we would need a sample of your solution to really understand what you want to do and be able to provide you with the help you are looking for.